# How to decrease brightness of laptop screen that was changed?

Tags: windows-7, display, hp-pavilion

I own http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c03061225 HP pavilion g6 1201tx laptop after using it for 2 years my laptop's screen display got damaged and i changed it through a local computer shop and he gave me not a standard company's screen.

Whenever I use windows power options-> Edit plan settings and set adjust plan brightness to almost 0 still it doesn't decrease as it used to with older original hp's screen.

Can anyone give me any solution using I can get less brightness?

Comment: Take it back and get them to put a properly compatible LCD panel in.

Comment: Cannot afford it, actually everything is working fine just brightness problem.